# Is it possible to modify the node edit form in a constraint validator?

Tags: 8, nodes

Is it possible to manipulate the node edit form after it fails a constraint validation?

My scenario is  as follows if a user attempts to save a node and fails the constraint validation a validation error is displayed, but also a paragraph field in the form should expand as if I clicked the "Add paragraph" button. The paragraph contains 2 text fields which a user just needs to fill out so that when they save again the validation passes.

So far I've managed to successfully create my constraint and constraint validator then added the constraint to entity of type node. The validation is working properly and outputting the error message, but I have not found a way to append a paragraph into the field and have it displayed when the form reloads.

Here is my validate() function in my class that implements ConstraintValidator

```php
  public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint) {
    if ($value instanceof NodeInterface) {
      $node = $value;
      if ('permitting_action' === $node->bundle()) {
        // Set last approved date.
        $last_approved_date = $this->getLastApprovedDate($node);
        $furthest_target_date = $this->projectDateOperation->getFurthestActionCurrentDate($node);
        $limit_date = (clone $last_approved_date)->add(DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day'));
        if (!$this->approvedBefore) {
          $limit_date->add(DateInterval::createFromDateString('29 day'));
        }
        if ($furthest_target_date->getTimestamp() > $limit_date->getTimestamp()) {
          $reason_date_change_paragraph = Paragraph::create([
            'type' => 'reason_for_date_changed',
          ]);
          $reason_date_change_paragraph->isNew();
          $node->get('field_reason_for_pause')->appendItem($reason_date_change_paragraph);
          $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->failedValidationMsg, ['%date' => $furthest_target_date->format('m/d/Y')])
            ->atPath('field_reason_for_pause')
            ->addViolation();
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

As you can see I'm attempting to add the paragraph in this snippet

```php
$reason_date_change_paragraph = Paragraph::create([
  'type' => 'reason_for_date_changed',
]);
$reason_date_change_paragraph->isNew();     
$node->get('field_reason_for_pause')->appendItem($reason_date_change_paragraph);
```

Comment: I have a similar problem, did you fin a solution?